# SQL Server - Null row not Showing?

Tags: sql, sql-server, null

Is there a way how to add null values rows, replacing with 0?

Ideally,I want to show data of all Month, if there is no data then count column set to zero.

Currently SQL query is not Returning Empty Rows and I'm getting output like this...

[image]

I'm using the code below to get the result set below that:

```
        SELECT  
        DATENAME(MONTH,A.Date) 'Month', COUNT(LateStatus) 'Count', 'Late' 'Type'
        FROM    
        Attendance1 A
        WHERE   
        A.EnrollId = '10000' AND A.Date BETWEEN '2016-01-01' AND '2016-08-31' AND LateStatus = 'L'
        GROUP BY 
        DATENAME(MONTH,A.Date)
```

Comment: Use left join with a calendar table. You can find many examples here on SO.

Comment: Here's a recommendation unrelated to your question: Don't use single quotes for the column aliases.

Comment: Make your *calendar table* on the fly using a CTE

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a recursive CTE (dynamically makes a *calendar table*):

```
With Months(mon) As 
    (Select dateAdd(month, datediff(month, 365, getdate()), 0) 
     Union All 
     Select DateAdd(month, 1, mon) from Months
     Where mon < getdate())
Select DATENAME(MONTH, m.mon ) 'Month', 
     COUNT(LateStatus) 'Count', 'Late' 'Type'
FROM months m 
     left join Attendance1 a
         on a.Date between m.mon and dateadd(month, 1, m.mon)
             and a.EnrollId = '10000' 
             and a.LateStatus = 'L'
GROUP BY DATENAME(MONTH, m.Mon)
```

A more generic function, to generate a range of integers which can be used for any expression, is this:

```
create function dbo.NumberList (@start integer, @end integer)
returns table
as Return
(
     With ints(aInt) As     
       (Select @start Union All
        Select aInt + 1 From ints
        Where aInt < @end)
     Select aInt from ints
)
```

Once this function has been created, you can use it to dynamically create any range of values of any type:

For months from 8 months ago to 3 months ago

```
Select i.aInt, Dateadd(month, i.aInt, 
        DateAdd(month, datediff(month(0, getdate()), 0))
From dbo.NumberList(-8, -3) i
```

Comment: Thank You @Charles-Bretana, thats what I'm Looking For, Works Perfectly.

Comment: I also want to Show from march to September in similar way ?

Comment: Change the value `365` to control how far back to go, (beginning of daterange),  and change the `Where mon < getdate()` to control the end of the daterange.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have *some* data for all months, you can do this using conditional aggregation.  That is, move the `WHERE` conditions to the `SELECT` using `CASE`:

```
SELECT DATENAME(MONTH,A.Date) as Mon,
       SUM(CASE WHEN A.EnrollId = '10000' AND LateStatus = 'L'
                THEN 1 ELSE 0
           END)  as cnt,
       'Late' as 'Type'
FROM Attendance1 A
WHERE AND A.Date BETWEEN '2016-01-01' AND '2016-08-31' 
GROUP BY DATENAME(MONTH, A.Date)
ORDER BY MIN(A.Date);
```

There are other methods, usually involving `LEFT JOIN`.  But this is the simplest if it solves the problem.

Comment: Not Working, Syntax Error